# How to access json array element in plsql-oracle 12c

Tags: sql, arrays, json, oracle

I am going to fetch one column in oracle 12c table which is clob type, column name is dynamic_fields, apparently it was a json format.

The data looks like this in the column:

```
{
  "App": 20187.7",
  "CTList":
    "[
      {\"lineOfBusiness\":\"0005",
       \"coverageId\":659376737,
       \"premiumPercentage\":0,
       \"lobInCt\":\"4CI5\"},
      {\"lineOfBusiness\":\"0005\",
       \"coverageId\":659376738,
       \"premiumPercentage\":0,
       \"lobInCt\":\"4CE5\"},
      {\"lineOfBusiness\":\"0005\",
       \"coverageId\":659376739,
       \"premiumPercentage\":1,
       \"lobInCt\":\"4CD5\"}]"
}
```

I want to use the json_value function to fetch the fields lineOfbusiness of the first element.

```sql
 json_value(dynamic_fields,'$.CTList[0].lineOfBusiness')
```

It returns null.

Is that anything wrong I did? I do not want to use json_table to fetch the array value since it will be needs to embed into another query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your `dynamic_fields` column's format. First, start by creating your table with a check constraint to make sure your column conforms json format ( 
*it's allowed to add a check constraint within DB version 12c* ) :

```
create table tab
(
 dynamic_fields clob constraint chk_dyn_fld 
 check (dynamic_fields is json)
);
```

If you try to insert you current value for `dynamic_fields` column, Oracle hurls by raising `ORA-02290` error ( `check constraint (<yourCurSchema>.CHK_DYN_FLD) violated` ), Fix your format by adding a double-quote just before `"App"`'s value (`^^"^^20187.7"`), and remove double-quotes from before beginning and after trailing parts of square brackets, and lastly try to replace backslashes by an empty string (`''`) by `replace()` function during the insertion :

```
insert into tab
values(replace('{
  "App": "20187.7",
  "CTList":
    [
      {\"lineOfBusiness\":\"0005",
       \"coverageId\":659376737,
       \"premiumPercentage\":0,
       \"lobInCt\":\"4CI5\"},
      {\"lineOfBusiness\":\"0005\",
       \"coverageId\":659376738,
       \"premiumPercentage\":0,
       \"lobInCt\":\"4CE5\"},
      {\"lineOfBusiness\":\"0005\",
       \"coverageId\":659376739,
       \"premiumPercentage\":1,
       \"lobInCt\":\"4CD5\"}]
}','\',''));
```

which doesn't raise any exception. And this time, you're able to get the desired value (`0005`) by your original query :

```
select json_value(dynamic_fields,'$.CTList[0].lineOfBusiness')
  from tab;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4e4eb7f85f7e99f6e4314527fd2314d7)</kbd>

Comment: @lionheart you're welcome. If you find helpful, please accept the answer.